# How to summarise useful information from existing dataset and combine in a new one?

Tags: stata

I am trying to summarise useful information from a survey dataset. This dataset contains information on the surveyed individuals' parents. One ID will associate four rows, containing information on their mother, father, mother-in-law and father-in-law. However, I am only interested in the surveyed person, rather than their parents.

```
* Example generated by -dataex-. To install: ssc install dataex
clear
input str12 ID byte(parentID ca001)
"010104101002" 1 2
"010104101002" 2 1
"010104101002" 3 1
"010104101002" 4 1
"010104102002" 1 2
"010104102002" 2 2
"010104102002" 3 2
"010104102002" 4 1
"010104103001" 1 2
"010104103001" 2 2
"010104103001" 3 2
"010104103001" 4 1
"010104104001" 1 2
"010104104001" 2 2
"010104104001" 3 2
"010104104001" 4 1
"010104105002" 1 2
"010104105002" 2 2
"010104105002" 3 2
"010104105002" 4 2
end
label values parentID parent
label def parent 1 "1 Father", modify
label def parent 2 "2 Mother", modify
label def parent 3 "3 Father-in-law", modify
label def parent 4 "4 Mother-in-law", modify
label values ca001 ca001
label def ca001 1 "1 Yes", modify
label def ca001 2 "2 No", modify
```

For example, `ca001` represents whether the respondents' parents (mother/father/mother-in-law/father-in-law) are still alive. What I need is a dummy variable, indicating the number of the ID's parents that are still alive (0-4).

I need to get rid of repeated IDs and have one unique ID for one observation. This is because I need to `merge` this dataset with other datasets by matching the unique ID from one dataset to another.

Comment: Use `dataex` (in Stata, install with `ssc inst dataex`) to give a readable data example. Images are not much use, unfortunately.

Comment: Oh, thx... I modified my question, is it correct now?

Comment: it doesn't look good...tho

Comment: Thanks for improving the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might work for you:

```
bysort ID: egen alive_parents = total(-(ca001-2))
keep ID alive_parents
duplicates drop
list

     +-------------------------+
     |     ID    alive_parents |
     |-------------------------|
  1. | 010104101002          3 |
  2. | 010104102002          1 |
  3. | 010104103001          1 |
  4. | 010104104001          1 |
  5. | 010104105002          0 |
     +-------------------------+
```

The idea is to subtract 2 from ca001 so that 0 == No and -1 == Yes and then take the negative of that so 0 == No and 1 == Yes, then sum by ID to get the total number of alive parents.

Then we drop the extra variables and are left with ID-alive_parents pairs that have 4 duplicates each, so we drop the duplicates.

Comment: Thank you so much!! This is exactly what I wanted!!

Comment: Note carefully: `egen, sum()` is undocumented as of Stata 9 up. The name is deprecated in favour of `egen, total()` because of the scope for confusion with the non-`egen` function `sum()` which produces cumulative or running sums instead.

Comment: Mine seems to be fine with `egen, sum()`... just ran the command

Comment: It will work with `egen, sum()`, but what Nick is saying is that it is better to use `egen, total()` so that it is not confused with Stata's separate `sum()` function which works somewhat differently